# Flutter - no class definition found exception on upgrading android native build to flutter build

Tags: android, flutter

I'm updating my Android native app to flutter. I've created a new project in flutter code base. Ive updated my version code and name but this exception im getting while installing flutter release APK over Android Native APK. Here is the exception

```
Class not found when unmarshalling: com.android.packageinstaller.InstallFlowAnalytics
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.packageinstaller.InstallFlowAnalytics
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2404)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2358)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2264)
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2614)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:920)
        at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:6183)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2695)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2157)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:6336)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:6114)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:170)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3986)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.packageinstaller.InstallFlowAnalytics
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324) 
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2404) 
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2358) 
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2264) 
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2614) 
        at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221) 
        at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:920) 
        at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:6183) 
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2695) 
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2157) 
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:6336) 
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:6114) 
        at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:170) 
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3986) 
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
11-23 21:34:04.451 29760-29760/? D/InstallAppProgress: Installation error code: -7
```

Pleas I'm stuck any hlp would be appreaciated.

Edit:
I found out that error code -7 means INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE. That means that signatures aren't matching. If I manage to change my key signing credentials on play store by reporting a lost key store and signing app with new keystore will solve the problem on playstore for existing users?

Comment: for an existing native apps (Android/iOS), it's recommended to add flutter as modules , you can follow this tutorial https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps

Comment: I've built a new complete app in flutter, what now? Also adding flutter to previous android project is in rpreview and isn't stable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Flutter APK installed successfully by uploading it to Play Console internal test track and updating it from there. Previouly I was trying to update it via putting APK in internal storage.